# Javascript Password Prompt Errors

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out how to correct the 2 problems I'm running into.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
function password() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter The Password','');
    while (testV < 2) {
        if (!pass1) 
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1 == "default") { //password here
            window.open('http://www.[redacted].com/downloads/documents/12-2011-project.psd'); //if password correct
            break;
        } 
        testV += 1;
        var pass1 = 
            prompt('Incorrect - Please Try Again.',''); //if password incorrect
    }
    if (pass1 != "password" & testV == 2)               
        history.go(-1);
    window.location = "/exit.html"; //redirects to here after success and opens download
}
```

**My first problem:** 
When clicking "*Cancel*" it prompts again. I just want it to simply disappear after I click cancel.

**Second:** 
After the 2 attempts are used when you click "*Cancel*", it redirects as if downloaded (no download is activated, which is good.)

What am I doing wrong, or what needs to be fixed?

Also, If a user just presses "OK" twice, there is no download activated, but it still redirects. I left a note on the exit page stating this. This doesn't bug me, but can that be fixed?; if not that's fine with me.

**SOLVED** (12/16 @ 9:30 AM)
Thanks to all that answered my first question!.

Comment: I would not rely on client-side javascript to protect files. Everyone can view the source and access them at any time.

Comment: Could you please post some HTML? I guess you could solve that by binding the right function to the "Cancel"-Button.

Comment: @luastoned : The people who will be viewing this page will have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @manticore : This is an external file and not directly embedded. There is just a button placed where I want it to show.

Comment: _"The people who will be viewing this page will have no idea how to do that"_ - Seriously? This is not a good approach to security.

Comment: Not only will a user be able to see the password, disable javascript, etc..., a user that knows the password can just share the URL of the download.

Comment: You guys, really.... I'm not concerned with security. I'm still in school and this is really only for fun. It's on my tumblr page. I honestly don't care.

Comment: @styro What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1 - If I understand you correctly, if the user cancels you want to abort all further processing so you can simply return from the `password()` function by changing this:

```
if (!pass1) 
  history.go(-1);
```

To this:

```
if (!pass1) {
  history.go(-1);
  return;
}
```

Otherwise if you want to stay in your function say `break` instead of `return` (as you already do for the correct password) to get out of the while loop and then add the appropriate if structure for that situation after the loop.

Problem 2 - No redirect will occur if you've already returned out of your `password()` function as shown above. If you're trying to cater for when the user has not cancelled but has gotten the password wrong then something like this:

```
if (pass1 != "password" & testV == 2)               
    history.go(-1);
else
    window.location = "/exit.html";
```

Though I'm not sure why you're testing the value of `testV` at that point.

**Note:** If you've got passwords in your JavaScript the user will be able to see the passwords by viewing your JS source.

Comment: To be honest I don't know why I put "testV" there. I'm still in school for web dev. So I still have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: The key point (other than the fact that putting your passwords into your JavaScript is a _really bad_ idea) is that the `.prompt()` function returns null if the user cancels. So just test for null (whether explicitly or just with `if(!pass1)` as you were already doing), and take appropriate action at that point. (And remember to accept whichever answer is most useful.)

Comment: This worked. I combined a pieces from yours and slava's post. Thanks! I appreciate it. Side note: This was only for fun and will serve little purpose as the only place it is on going is on my tumblr page. It will download a password protected RAR file instead of a PSD (dummy link for post). I realize that JavaScript has little security and is not the way to go. I knew that before posting as I clearly wrote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to 'fix' it:

```
function password() {
    var counter = 0;
    var promtText = {'Please Enter The Password', 'Incorrect - Please Try Again.'};
    while (counter < 2) {
       var passw = prompt(promtText[counter],'');
        if (passw == "default") { //password here
            window.open('http://www.[redacted].com/downloads/documents/12-2011-project.psd'); //if password correct
            break;
        } 
        counter++;
    }
    if (passw == "password")               
        window.location = "/exit.html"; //redirects to here after success and opens download
    else
        history.go(-1);
}
```

There does seem to be some confusion here about what the correct password is :)

Also, it is true you should not rely on client-side validation, especially anything security related.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if `pass1` is true because it's not when you cancel the form.
You have to ask for `!pass1` in the last if-clause too.
Here is my attempt:

```
function password() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter The Password','');
while (testV < 2 && pass1) {
    if (!pass1)
        history.go(-1);
    if (pass1 == "default") { //password here
        window.open('http://www.[redacted].com/downloads/documents/12-2011-project.psd'); //if    password correct
        break;
    }
    testV += 1;
    var pass1 =
        prompt('Incorrect - Please Try Again.',''); //if password incorrect
}
if (pass1 != "password" & testV == 2 & !pass1) history.go(-1);
window.location = "/exit.html"; //redirects to here after success and opens download
}
```

Comment: If the user cancels from the first prompt that will skip over the while loop (due to your change to the while test), but the if test after the loop will be false because testV will still be 1.

Comment: what about now? I added !pass1 to that particular if clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please note the variables and **do not** hardcode the real password and number of tries

Also note that when promt window is canceled, it returns `null`, so you should check that `pass1 != null`.

```
function password() {
    var real_pass = "default";
    var num_of_tries = 4;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter The Password','');
    var testV = 1;

    if(pass1 != null) {
        if (pass1 == real_pass) {
            window.open('http://www.[redacted].com/downloads/documents/12-2011-project.psd'); //if password correct
        }
        else {
            while (testV < num_of_tries && pass1 != null) {
                var pass1 = prompt('Incorrect - Please Try Again.','');             
                if (pass1 == real_pass) {
                    window.open('http://www.[redacted].com/downloads/documents/12-2011-project.psd'); //if password correct
                    break;
                }
                testV++;

            }
        }
    }
    history.go(-1);
    window.location = "/exit.html"; //redirects to here after success and opens download
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked nearly perfect. Thanks! But it doesn't redirect after the download is activated.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't redirect? If password is right, it opens download page and what do  you expect it to do after?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. In my original post coding, when entering the correct password, the script gets the download and redirects when the "OK" button is pressed. Yours works perfect with the prompts and download link, but it does not redirect to "exit.html".

Comment: "OK" button is you HTNL code or you mean ok button of browser that asks "Do you want to download it?"

Comment: The "OK" that asks "Do you want to download". Once pressed with correct password, it downloads but does not redirect the page.

Comment: It was Dreamweaver. not the script.